# How to pass values from MVC to Angular2 (RC.5) when boostrapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I want to pass some server generated configuration from MVC to an angular2 app when bootstrapping my angular2 application. The configuration is required by various services. In the earlier releases of angular2 it was possible to pass in the config as a provider when calling the bootstrap method, however this method has been deprecated in the latest release in favour of platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrapModule. I noticed the bootstrapModule method has a compilerOptions parameter which allows providers to be supplied but these don't seem to filter through to the components/services and I'm struggling to find any documentation on the topic.

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<script src="/lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="/app/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appConfig = {
        prop1: '@Model.Prop1',
        prop2: '@Model.Prop2',
        prop3: '@Model.Prop3'
    };
    System.import('/app/main')
        .then(main => main.bootstrap(appConfig), console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

**Main.ts:**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppConfig } from './app-config';

export function bootstrap(appConfig: AppConfig) {
    var compilerOptions = { providers: [{ provide: AppConfig, useValue: appConfig }] };
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, compilerOptions);
}
```

Can someone please explain how to pass in server generated values like this with the latest angular2 release? (rc.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just figured it out, platformBrowserDynamic takes providers as parameter and these do make their way through to all the services etc.

So main.ts becomes:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppConfig } from './config-types';

export function bootstrap(appConfig: AppConfig) {
    var providers = [{ provide: AppConfig, useValue: appConfig }];
    platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

Hopefully this will be useful to someone else!